# How to make Mathematica treat y/x as a one variable?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I would like to make for example: $\frac{\partial\frac{2y}{x}}{\partial\frac{y}{x}}$. However, when I put it into Mathematica as `D[2y/x,{y/x}]` it does not recognize y/x as a one variable? Is there any way how to do it?

Comment: `Derivative[1][2 # &][y/x]`?

Comment: Replace with a new variable? There are many threads in MSE discussing ways to go about this. It is not clear from this question whether that is quite what is wanted though.

Comment: `Dt[2 y/x]/Dt[y/x] // Simplify`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
expr1 = Inactivate[D[2 y/x, y/x], D] /. y :> z*x
```

[image]

Then

```
Activate[expr1]

(*   2   *)
```

Have fun!